# TestNG.xml - Error "The content of element type "classes" must match "(class*,parameter*)"."

Tags: xml, selenium, testng

The below `xml` file is my `TestNG.xml`. This shows up error when I added methods tag:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite">

    <listeners>
        <listener class-name="Util.Listnr" />
    </listeners>
    <test thread-count="5" name="Test">
        <classes>
            <class name="AWD_Tests.NewTest" />
            <methods>
                <include name="AWDRetrieval" />
                <include name="function" />

                <exclude name="AWDCreation" />
            </methods>

        </classes>
    </test> <!-- Test -->
</suite> <!-- Suite -->
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Exist error in your xml file , tag `<class>` should be not closed, try next:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
    <suite name="Suite">

        <listeners>
            <listener class-name="Util.Listnr" />
        </listeners>
        <test thread-count="5" name="Test">
            <classes>
                <class name="AWD_Tests.NewTest"><!-- close tag is redundant here-->
                    <methods>
                        <include name="AWDRetrieval" />
                        <include name="function" />

                        <exclude name="AWDCreation" />
                    </methods>
                </class><!-- close tag should be here-->

            </classes>
        </test> 
    </suite>
```

Answer (score 4):

Tried many options, finally removing doctype header worked for me(with a warning!)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
```

Comment: Don't know if this is the correct way - But it worked for me as well . Why this happens all of a sudden ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For me there was a hidden/barely visible period within the `<classes>` tags. Check your code.